# Squid sticks to credentials until reloaded

Tags: active-directory, squid, samba4

I have successfully setup a squid server authenticating to kerberos/ntlm/ldap to a samba4 server and they all work just fine (its such a beautiful thing!!! :D)

I am now starting to make my ACLs and I want one particular group of users to have unrestricted access.

The thing is, when I add my user to the AD group Internet Irrestrito and open up my browser it works, I remove my user from the group and it still can access the internet, if I do a squid -k reconfigure, and reload the website or reopen the browser, then it denies my access as it should have done before.

Given that I cant just go reloading squid every single time I change a user group, what do I need to do so that squid will recognize changes in the user's groups without reloading it?

I've changed the ttl on the ldap auth to a really low setting (right now its set to 5 hours) and same situation happens.
Also, on an old squid box they have here in the company the same ttl of 5 hours is there and once we change the user from that old network ldap server the user only needs to restart his browser and its done!

Here is my squid.conf

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

auth_param negotiate program /usr/local/squid/libexec/negotiate_wrapper -d --ntlm     /usr/local/squid/libexec/ntlm_auth --diagnostics --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp --    domain=testserver.LAN --kerberos /usr/local/squid/libexec/negotiate_kerberos_auth -d -s     HTTP/servidor-005.testserver.lan@testserver.LAN
auth_param negotiate children 10
auth_param negotiate keep_alive off

auth_param ntlm program /usr/local/squid/libexec/ntlm_auth --diagnostics --helper-    protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp --domain=testserver.LAN
auth_param ntlm children 10
auth_param ntlm keep_alive off

auth_param basic program /usr/local/squid/libexec/basic_ldap_auth -d -R -b "dc=testserver,dc=lan" -D squid@testserver.lan -W /usr/local/squid/etc/ldappass -f     sAMAccountName=%s -h servidor-001.testserver.lan
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic credentialsttl 5 hours  
auth_param basic realm testserver Proxy Server

external_acl_type internet_irrestrito %LOGIN /usr/local/squid/libexec/ext_ldap_group_acl -R -K -b "cn=Users,dc=testserver,dc=lan" -D squid@testserver.lan -W             /usr/local/squid/etc/ldappass -f "(&(objectclass=person)(sAMAccountName=%u)    (memberof=cn=Internet Irrestrito,cn=Users,dc=testserver,dc=lan))" -h servidor-    001.testserver.lan

acl auth proxy_auth REQUIRED

acl Irrestrito external internet_irrestrito Internet\ Irrestrito

http_access allow Irrestrito auth
http_access deny !auth
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

http_port 3128
cache_mgr ti@testserver.com.br
access_log /usr/local/squid/var/logs/access.log squid
coredump_dir /usr/local/squid/var/cache/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

Any ideas are welcome, I had no success searching over the web for the last two days :(

Comment: A friend recommended me to just put the reload on cron, I refuse to believe this is the only solution. Still looking around the web...

Comment: seems we have the same problem. I have tried with authenticate_ttl directive but no success.